# docker and elastic beanstalk container stopped unexpectedly and permission denied

Tags: playframework-2.0, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to extend [this docker image](https://github.com/Ir1sh/dockeractivator) which is provisioned with ansible and build successfully on [docker hub](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/ir1sh/dockeractivator/) at least, part of this image includes a user called play which owns a directory called /home/play/Code that has 755 permissions.  I am using boot2docker on mac

This is my docker file locally

```
FROM ir1sh/dockeractivator
MAINTAINER Mark Moore
EXPOSE 9000
```

which builds ok and when I run

```
docker run --rm -it -v "/my/local/dir:/home/play/Code" -p 9000:9000 300b01a6199c
```

the container starts correctly and I get a session with user root starting in /home/play/Code.  If I add -u play to that commade I get a session with the play user instead in the same directory.

Now if I push that container to elastic beanstalk with their cli tool I get the following error

> Output: [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/04run.sh]
>   command failed with error code 1:
>   /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/04run.sh
>   b07ae15d619ad90441f6f410a31a7d51885151c92cd8675c5d8e47f63b43dd95
>   Docker container quit unexpectedly after launch: Docker container quit
>   unexpectedly on Sun Dec 21 13:36:06 UTC 2014:. Check snapshot logs for
>   details..

The logs aren't very enlightening

Now per another suggestion I dont have a CMD or an ENTRYPOINT in my docker file so I add those.

```
FROM ir1sh/dockeractivator
MAINTAINER Mark Moore
EXPOSE 9000
ENTRYPOINT ["/home/play/Code", "-DFOREGROUND"]
CMD []
```

The image builds but now when I try docker run with the same options as above I get

> exec: "/home/play/Code": permission denied2014/12/21 13:34:33 Error
>   response from daemon: Cannot start container
>   2703462a68a32e8d774e9b4d8cbc3c809e79f53bb1d08f0398b45436d07546a3:
>   exec: "/home/play/Code": permission denied

This happens whether I try to start the session as root or as play.  I get the same error if I push this dockerfile to elastic beanstalk so its not related to boot2docker  Any idea what my permission problem is here?  I have tried changing that directories permission to 777 to no avail

edit1: running as privileged also does not help

edit2: changing the dockerfile to

```
FROM ir1sh/dockeractivator
MAINTAINER Mark Moore
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["bash"]
```

Allows me to run the container locally but afterpushing to elastic beanstalk I get the container quit unexpectedly error again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running without -it when you run locally, this properly replicates the scenario of running on elastic beanstalk as beanstalk will not run the container in interactive mode. Some processes don't handle non-interactive shells too well. This is certainly the case with the scenario when you use bash as your CMD. In non-interactive mode the bash shell would exit immediately.

I also think you are still not clear on what EntryPoint and CMD do, I see that `/home/play/Code` is a directory, The first string in the always needs to be an executable.

For example if you have ENTRYPOINT ["A","B"] and CMD ["C","D"] this is equivalent to issuing the following command on the terminal `A B C D`. A better example would be:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["ls","-a","-l"]
CMD ["/var/log"]

# This maps too
ls -a -l /var/log
```

The reason you have two options ENTRYPOINT can not be overridden at run time where as CMD can. i.e. I can docker run the following to change the directory that the ls command would list but I can't change the fact that this container is going to run an ls command

```
docker run -it myContainer /tmp
```

Comment: so when I leave out the -it and attempt run, it dosn't enter the container with a session and when I run docker ps it shows no running container so it sounds like your suspicions are correct.  So I am not really sure of the purpose of the entrypoint and cmd.  basically I just want this container to start and then I want to provision the rest with ansible.  I can kick of ansible manually locally and was planning on using .ebextensions commands to do that on elasticbeanstalk

Comment: is there a command I can replace the bash command with that just does nothing and leaves the conatiner running?

Comment: docker logs [CONTAINER_NAME/ID] should tell you what happened to the container that died. Its probably not very useful in this case as normally processes that don't handle headless mode don't log very well either. tail -f /some/log/file will keep the container running and then you can use docker exec -it bash to get into it

Comment: ok thanks again.  so in my case if i add ENTRYPOINT ["ls", "-a", "-l"] CMD ["/home/play/Code] and run it with -it I get the expected output of ls -a -l of that directory....great but the container does not stay running.  Basically at this point  in the setup I dont have any specific task I want to run so is there something I can do that will keep the container running that will also work when pushed to elastic beanstalk

Comment: I guess I could use the CMD to kick of the rest of my provisioning with ansible but will the container keep running when that provisioning is complete?  the end of the provisioning will include the starting of a server

Comment: As long as you run the server in foregorund as the final step of your provisioning script then the docker container should be fine in beanstalk too. You can use Supervisor (https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/) as the final command in your script if your server does not have a headless foreground mode.

Comment: thank you your comments are getting me much further.  if I go the supervisord route do I actually need to run something with supervisord or is just running the supervisord process itself enough

Comment: Yes, if you follow the linked tutorial but use just the first 2 lines of supervisord.conf i.e. [supervisord] nodaemon=true. When you run the container it will keep running, even without interactive mode.

Comment: You can override ENTRYPOINT with --entrypoint http://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#entrypoint-default-command-to-execute-at-runtime